# How can I get Ruby curses to respond properly to arrow keys?

Tags: ruby, curses, arrow-keys

### TL;DR

How can I get Ruby curses to respond properly to arrow keys? The KEY_UP constant doesn't seem to match my input.

### Environment and Problem Descriptions

I am running Ruby 2.1.2 with the [curses 1.0.1 gem](https://github.com/ruby/curses). I'm trying to enable arrow-key navigation with curses. I've enabled [Curses#getch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-getch) to fetch a single key without waiting for the carriage return by calling [Curses#cbreak](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-cbreak), and this is working fine for the <kbd>k</kbd> character. However, I really want to enable arrow key navigation, and not just HJKL for movement.

Currently, the up-arrow prints 27 within my program, which seems like the correct [ordinal value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-ord) my keyboard gives for the up-arow key:

```
"^[[A".ord
#=> 27
```

and which *should* be matched by the [Curses KEY_UP constant](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses/Key.html). It isn't, and so falls through to the else statement to display the ordinal value. The up-arrow key also leaves <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as two separate characters at the command prompt when the ruby program exits, which might indicate that [Curses#getch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-getch) isn't capturing the key press properly.

### My Ruby Code

```
require 'curses'
include  Curses

begin
  init_screen
  cbreak
  noecho
  keypad = true

  addstr 'Check for up arrow or letter k.'
  refresh
  ch = getch
  addch ?\n

  case ch
  when KEY_UP
    addstr "up arrow \n"
  when ?k
    addstr "up char \n"
  else
    addstr "%s\n" % ch
  end

  refresh
  sleep 1
ensure
  close_screen
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line to enable the keypad, you're actually creating a local variable called 'keypad' because that method is on the class `Curses::Window`.
Since you're not making your own windows (apart from with `init_screen`), you can just refer to the standard one using the stdscr method.  If I change line 8 to:

```
stdscr.keypad = true
```

then you sample code works for me.

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm not sure I understand why the *keypad=* setter needs an explicit receiver when none of the other methods do, and when I don't have to qualify Curses::Key::KEY_UP. Remember, I used `include Curses`. So why does #keypad= seem to be unique in this way?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used curses for a long time (and when I did, it wasn't with ruby) so I can't answer your question :(

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because it solved my immediate problem. Hopefully someone else will help us both with the "why" somewhere down the line. Thanks for your prompt solution!