# How to detect Return or Enter key properly when using Curses

Tags: ruby, ncurses, curses

I am wanting to learn Ruby so I thought I'd try and learn it and Curses at the same time.  I am creating a navigation menu that allows the user to select options which will run system commands.

I have gotten to the point where my navigation menu is created and I can cycle through options using the arrow keys.

Now I am trying to read the Enter key as input and run a system command when Enter is pressed. Example:

```
    input = menu.getch
    if input == ENTER
```

in

```
  position = 3 if position < 0
  position = 0 if position > 3
  draw_menu(menu, position)
  if position == 0
    draw_info menu, 'You selected option 0'
    input = menu.getch
    if input == ENTER
      menu.clear
      menu.refresh
      puts (system 'ls')

    end
```

When the Enter key is pressed, the system command does work(kind of) but I am having a problem where the system command is also run if the option is just selected or highlighted.  I only want it to work if the Enter key is pressed.

If I change it to

```
    if input == 'k'
```

The system command only runs when the Enter key is pressed.  It will not run when highlighted or selected.  This is the way I want it to work.

Any ideas on how I can get the Enter key to function the same as the 'k' key?

Here is my code.

```
require 'curses'
include Curses

# Top Lie
SCREEN_WIDTH       = 90
HEADER_HEIGHT      = 4
HEADER_WIDTH       = SCREEN_WIDTH

# Bottom Line
SCREEN_WIDTH2      = 90
HEADER_HEIGHT2      = 1
HEADER_WIDTH2       = SCREEN_WIDTH2

Curses.init_screen
Curses.curs_set(0)  # Invisible cursor

Curses.start_color

Curses.noecho # echo or noecho to display user input
Curses.nonl
Curses.raw
Curses.stdscr.nodelay = 1

Curses.init_pair(1, Curses::COLOR_WHITE, Curses::COLOR_BLUE)
Curses.init_pair(2, Curses::COLOR_WHITE, Curses::COLOR_BLUE)

begin

  # Top Line
  header_window = Curses::Window.new(HEADER_HEIGHT, HEADER_WIDTH, 0, 0)   # (height, width, top, left)
  header_window.color_set(1)
  header_window << "Curses example".center(HEADER_WIDTH)
  header_window.refresh

  # Bottom Line
  header2_window = Curses::Window.new(HEADER_HEIGHT, HEADER_WIDTH, 23, 0)
  header2_window.color_set(2)
  header2_window << "Curses example".center(HEADER_WIDTH)
  header2_window.refresh

  # Building a static window

    def draw_menu(menu, active_index=nil)
      ["This is option 0.", "This is option 1.", "This is option 2.", "This is option 3."].each_with_index do |element, index|
      # "w" for word array
      # It's a shortcut for arrays
        menu.setpos(index + 1, 1)
        menu.attrset(index == active_index ? A_STANDOUT : A_NORMAL)
        menu.addstr("#{index} - %-10s" % element)   # %-Xs makes sure array words line up evenly if you place index after element
                                                    # you can change 17 to another number
      end
      menu.setpos(5, 1)
    end

    def draw_info(menu, text)
      menu.setpos(6, 1)  # sets the position of move up and down
                         # for example, menu.setpos(1, 10) moves to another
                         # location
      menu.attrset(A_NORMAL)
      menu.addstr text
    end

    position = 0

    menu = Window.new(20, 70, 2, 2)  # (height, width, top, left)
    menu.keypad = true  # enable keypad which allows arrow keys
    #menu.box('|', '-')
    draw_menu(menu, position)
    while ch = menu.getch
      stdscr.keypad = true
      case ch
      when KEY_UP, 'w'
        #draw_info menu, 'move up'
        position -= 1
      when KEY_DOWN, 's'
        #draw_info menu, 'move down'
        position += 1
      when 'x'
        exit
      end
      position = 3 if position < 0
      position = 0 if position > 3
      draw_menu(menu, position)
      if position == 0
        draw_info menu, 'You selected option 0'
        input = menu.getch
        if input == 'k'  # I want this to be ENTER
            menu.clear
            menu.refresh
            puts (system 'ls')  # This does not work well.  I need to fix it.

        end
      elsif position == 1
        draw_info menu, 'You selected option 1'
      elsif position == 2
        draw_info menu, 'You selected option 2'
      else position == 3
        draw_info menu, 'You selected option 3'
      end       
    end

rescue => ex
  Curses.close_screen
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be additional problems, but the one you're likely running into is that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on your keyboard usually is not what curses (ncurses) calls `KEY_ENTER`.  Instead, that's usually assigned to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the *numeric keypad* (and it sends an escape sequence when *keypad* mode is enabled).  That's discussed in *[proper way of catching control+key in ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923546/proper-way-of-catching-controlkey-in-ncurses/43924525#43924525)*.

Also, your initialization using

```
Curses.raw
```

prevents curses from returning `KEY_ENTER` in any case.  That is, curses wouldn't recognize the escape sequence assigned to that code.  You might want to try

```
Curses.cbreak
Curses.stdscr.keypad = 1
```

which (unless something not shown is making `KEY_UP` and `KEY_DOWN` work) will help with the other `KEY_xxx` symbols, and where you're expecting *"ENTER"*, to accept a newline **`\n`** character.  That's more likely to do what you expect.

Further reading:

- [case KEY_ENTER not functioning as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706309/case-key-enter-not-functioning-as-expected)
- [How can I get Ruby curses to respond properly to arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319194/how-can-i-get-ruby-curses-to-respond-properly-to-arrow-keys)
- [Ruby Keyboard event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897687/ruby-keyboard-event-handling/897763#897763)