# Enter key not recognized with curses

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

I have this sample code where I write on the screen if the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed but when I run the code nothing happens and nothing is written on the screen.
I know I can use `stdscr.getch()`, but for some reason I don't want to use them.

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    while 1:
        Key = stdscr.getkey()
        if Key == curses.KEY_ENTER:
            stdscr.addstr(0,0,'u pressed enter')
            stdscr.refresh()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: maybe first use `print(Key, curses.KEY_ENTER)` to see what you get when you press key and compare it with `curses.KEY_ENTER`. Maybe you have to compare `Key` with different value - maybe some `KEYPAD_ENTER`. OR maybe `getkey()` wasn't created for `ENTER`

Comment: on my computer with Linux I have to use `if Key == '\n':` or `if ord(Key) == 10:`

Comment: "but for some reason I don't want to use them" — why is that?

Comment: @martineau I tested it and `getch()` always gives key code (integer) so you have to compare with `ord("a")` or `97`. With `getkey()` you can compare directly with `"a"`. But better is `get_wch()` - it also gives `"a"` instead of `97` and only `get_wch` works with native chars. I added testing code in answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Return or Enter key properly when using Curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536217/how-to-detect-return-or-enter-key-properly-when-using-curses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer with Linux I have to use

```
if Key == '\n':
```

or

```
if ord(Key) == 10:
```

It seems `getkey()` doesn't treat `ENTER` as special key and it doesn't return `curses.KEY_ENTER`. OR maybe it depens on terminal - some of then may have option to define code for `ENTER` and/or `BACKSPACE`.

**EDIT:**

I found out that for special keys `getkey()` gives me strings like `"KEY_LEFT"` instead of integer value `curses.KEY_LEFT`. But `get_wch()` gives integer value `curses.KEY_LEFT` (and char for normal keys) - but it still treats `ENTER` as `'\n'`

---

You should simply use `print()` to check what you get in variables.

```
print(Key, type(Key))
```

and when you see it is `<class str>`

```
print( ord(Key) )
```

You could also compare it with constant

```
print( Key, curses.KEY_ENTER, Key == curses.KEY_ENTER )
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tested it with this code on Linux Mint 20 MATE, Python 3.8, in Mate-Terminal.

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):

    while True:
        #key = stdscr.getch()     # always integer (keycode), native/Polish char WRONG (two wrong integers)
        #key = stdscr.getkey()    # char or string (keyname), native/Polish char WRONG (two wrong chars)
        key = stdscr.get_wch()   # char or integer (keycode), native/Polish char OK
        
        print('key:', type(key), key, end='\n\r')
        
        if isinstance(key, str):
            print('len:', len(key), end='\n\r')
            if len(key) == 1:            
                print('ord:', ord(key), end='\n\r')
        else:
            print('keyname:', curses.keyname(key), end='\n\r')

        print('---', end='\n\r')

        stdscr.refresh()

# --- main ---

#print('curses.KEY_ENTER:', curses.KEY_ENTER)
#print('curses.KEY_BACKSPACE:', curses.KEY_BACKSPACE)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

For me the best is `get_wch()` because it works correctly with native (Polish) chars.

```
getch()   - always integer (keycode),  native/Polish char WRONG (two wrong integers)
getkey()  - char or string (keyname),  native/Polish char WRONG (two wrong chars)
get_wch() - char or integer (keycode), native/Polish char OK
```

---

**EDIT:**

For key `F1` it needs

- string `"KEY_F(1)"` for `getkey()`

  ```
  getkey() == "KEY_F(1)"
  ```
- integer `265` or `curses.KEY_F1` for `get_wch()` and `getch()`

  ```
  get_wch() == 265
  get_wch() == curses.KEY_F1

  getch() == 265
  getch() == curses.KEY_F1
  ```

Comment: yup thanks for the great explanation i used '\n' and its works perfectly fine thanks

Comment: btw how can i read the f1 - f12 keys using this method ?

Comment: if you run my code and press `F1` then you see `key: <class 'int'> 265
`, and `keyname: KEY_F(1)` . If you use `getkey` (which send special keys as string) then you have to compare with string `getkey() == "KEY_F(1)"`, if you use `getch` or `get_wch` (which send special keys as integer) then you have to compare with integer `get_wch() == 265` but you can use also `get_wch() == curses.KEY_F1`

Comment: yeah its working but i dont know why it doesnt work on my stock terminal when i use other terminal its works perfectly fine

Comment: as I know long time ago there was many different terminals (hardware) and current terminals (software) can emulate different versions. You could use my program to see codes when you press `F1`.  Maybe it helps to see what codes you have to use in program.

Comment: yeah no worries i am now using xterm and its works perfectly fine